# What is the prob that the seq obtained is inc (ie. nondecreasing)

Tags: statistics

Given n distinct numbers, k numbers are picked out, 1 by 1 w/ replacement to get a seq of numbers. What is the prob that this seq is increasing?

I know that since non-decreasing seq are allowed, there are in addition n constant seq on top of the strictly increasing probability of C(n,k)/n^k. But I am stuck from here...

Answer (score 0):

Let $F(k,n)$ be number of $k$-tuples such that $X_1 \le \ldots \le X_k$.
Conditioning on $X_k$, we get $$F(k,n) = \sum_{m=1}^n F(k-1, m)$$
Thus $F(k,n) - F(k,n-1) = F(k-1,n)$.  Boundary conditions are
$F(k,1) = 1$ and $F(1,n) = n$.

It is easy to show that 
$$ F(k,n) = {n+k-1 \choose k-1} $$

Then the probability is $F(k,n)/n^k$.